# regex for C programming within a file that has been opened

Tags: c, regex, printf

I'm doing an assignment in C where I'm making a hangman game that randomly selects a line from a text document that we have been supplied.

At the moment I have the 2 words displaying but with a comma in between and I can't find the proper way to change it so that its a space.

my current code is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static char words[288][25];
    FILE *file;
    int i, j;
    size_t count, n;
    char word[25];

    srand(time(NULL));
    file = fopen("/home/dan/Downloads/hangman_text.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL){
        printf("The file cannot be opened.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    count = 0;
    while(1==fscanf(file, "%24s", word)){
        if(count == 288)
            break;
        strcpy(words[count++], word);
    }


    fclose(file);
    n = count;

    if(n > RAND_MAX){
        int part;
        size_t random = 0;
        i = n / RAND_MAX;
        part = rand() % (i+1);
        if(part == i){
            j = n % RAND_MAX;
            if(j != 0)
                random = random + RAND_MAX*part + rand() % j;
            else
                random = random + RAND_MAX*(part-1) + rand();
        } else {
            random = random + RAND_MAX*part + rand();
        }
        printf("%s\n", words[random]);
    } else {
        int random = rand() % n;
        printf("%s\n", words[random]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with regex? You aren't even using any regex library in your code

Comment: You'll be better off using fgets for line based text file. Read entire line, then process it.

Comment: sorry i've explained this poorly, at the moment it pulls from the text file a line of text that is formatted like this
"zoo,place"
i need to get the length of both zoo and place individually so i need to split it into 2 words so i was thinking of using regex to change the comma into a space and then read them individually

Comment: @Dan: to kill an ant, you just squish it with your finger, or shoe. You do not need a rocket launcher for that. Same with intending to use a regex for solving your programing problem. Just loop through the string, get the two words, and then use the `strlen()` function.